# MSBuild building project and referenced project with same configuration

Tags: build, configuration, msbuild

I'm using MSBuild to build a project with configuration set to a custom configuration. I have a referenced project (a library) which does not have any cutom configuration set to it. The issue is, it seems like MSBuild is building the project and the project references with the same configuration.

I'm using this command:

```
msbuild.exe <path>\<project>.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:OutDir=<dirpath> /p:Configuration=<CustomConfig>
```

Im having the follow error:

> C:\Program Files
>    (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(724,5):
>    error : The OutputPath property is not set for project
>    'referencedProject.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination  of Configuration and Platform for this
>    project.  Configuration='CustomConfig'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing
>    this message because you are trying to build a project without a
>    solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or
>    Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [path\ReferencedProjectcsproj]

I cannot find anything related online, if anyone can point me to anything or help me out with this, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around, posting it here in case someone ends up in the same scenario.

The project library did not have the custom configurtation so, i had to edit the csproj file to change the condition of build configuration to this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' Or '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' != 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
```

This will force the compiler to take the leading configurations if it is in release mode or any custom configuration that is mentioned.

I have no found any way that will command MSBuild to choose different configuration project dependencies.